# How to change the index title location, without changing other chapter title locations?

Tags: titlesec, indexing

[image]

I've changed my chapter title locations using  `titlesec` . However, the index title changes too. How am I able to use titlesec without changing the index location? I am currently using the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside, openleft]{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\newcommand{\boldindex}[1]{\textcolor{DarkPurple}{\textbf{#1}}\nouppercase{\index{#1}}}
\makeindex[intoc]

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{}{-2pt}{\hskip5cm \centering \Huge \bfseries \mbox}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{186pt}{-120pt}{27pt}

\renewcommand\indexname{Begrippen Index}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\boldindex{Test}\\
\boldindex{tEst}\\
\boldindex{teSt}\\
\boldindex{tesT}

\printindex 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might use the `numberless` key to have a different layout for unnumbered chapters.

Comment: Have you tried another different `\titleformat{\chapter}...` just before `\printindex`?